# How to replace generic icon

Tags: google-apps-script

I am creating an add-on for Google Forms. The script extracts data from the form and sends the results to the Google spreadsheet. What I would like to do, if possible, is replace the generic add-on icon (refer to the screenshot below. The icon is highlighted) with an icon that I have. How would I achieve it?

[image]

The following is where I am creating the add-on menu:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  FormApp.getUi()
      .createAddonMenu()
      //.createMenu("MOATT Add-On")
      .addItem('Show Modal Extract Form Q&A', 'showModal')
      .addItem('Show Sidebar Modal Extract Form Q&A', 'showSideBar')
      .addItem('Show Modeless Extract Form Q&A', 'showModeless')
      .addItem('About MOATT Add-On', 'showAbout')
      .addToUi();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Apps Script have methods to add custom menus but not to change the built-in user interface.

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-app#getui
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui.html